# How I can fix the .env problem when I want to export my private key in brownie

Tags: python, brownie

I have the exact same problem that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70103360/brownie-does-not-export-env-variables), I'm learning in the Patrick Collins course in this [part](https://youtu.be/M576WGiDBdQ?t=17876) with the following code

```js
from brownie import accounts, config, SimpleStorage, network


def deploy_simple_storage():
    account = get_account()
    simple_storage = SimpleStorage.deploy({"from": account})
    stored_value = simple_storage.retrieve()
    print(stored_value)
    transaction = simple_storage.store(15, {"from": account})
    transaction.wait(1)
    updated_stored_value = simple_storage.retrieve()
    print(updated_stored_value)


def get_account():
    if network.show_active() == "development":
        return accounts[0]
    else:
        return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])


def main():
    deploy_simple_storage()
```

- I have brownie v1.14.6
- I have .env and brownie-config.ymal in the    same repository
- I already tried import os on a line, then
  print(os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY")) and and returns me the same error and
  "none"

I think that is a problem with .env (Variables Environment, as well I already tried add manually the PATH variables and still don't works) returns me the same error:

```js
PS C:\Users\ericl\demos\brownie_simple_storage> brownie run .\scripts\deploy.py --network rinkeby
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.14.6 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieSimpleStorageProject is the active project.

Running 'scripts\deploy.py::main'...
  File "c:\users\ericl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 49, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "c:\users\ericl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 103, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File ".\scripts\deploy.py", line 23, in main
    deploy_simple_storage()
  File ".\scripts\deploy.py", line 5, in deploy_simple_storage
    account = get_account()
  File ".\scripts\deploy.py", line 19, in get_account
    return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
  File "c:\users\ericl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 132, in add
    w3account = web3.eth.account.from_key(private_key)
_utils\decorators.py", line 18, in _wrapper
    return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\ericl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\eth_account\account.py", line 246, in from_key
    key = self._parsePrivateKey(private_key)
  File "c:\users\ericl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\decorators.py", line 18, in _wrapper
    return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\ericl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\eth_account\account.py", line 696, in _parsePrivateKey
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The private key must be exactly 32 bytes long, instead of 0 bytes.
```

Note: I use Windows 10

Comment: Well, did you do `export PRIVATE_KEY=<your private key>`?

Comment: @TimRoberts OP mentions `.env` file, so I don't think that is relevant. Usually you use a program like `dotenv` that reads the `.env` file, parses it and puts the values in the env and launches the child processes so I expect OP is doing something like `dotenv python3 brownie ...` and this should work if the `.env` syntax is correct etc. But OP posted irrelevant code so not sure how to help.  I assume the `brownie` process automatically reads the `.env`, but maybe that's what OP is missing...

Comment: That's a good point to check, because `os.environ` doesn't know anything about `.env`.  Someone would have to import it.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for your help, I will trial If I can fix this